# Explain this python string operation s[:6][::-1]

Tags: python

I am new to python. Please anybody explain the following string operations

```
s="abcdefghijklmnop"
```

`print s[:6][::-1]`  #is it first calculating `s[:6]` and then operating the result with `[::-1]` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```py
"abcdefghijklmnop"[:6][::-1]
```

1. Take first 6 characters (`abcdef`).
2. Read the result from the end to the beginning (`fedcba`).

There is an other *better* way to get this result:

```py
"abcdefghijklmnop"[5::-1]
```